# Place holder is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Place holder is not working in IE-9,so I used the below code for place holder.

```
 jQuery(function () {
     debugger;
     jQuery.support.placeholder = false;
     test = document.createElement('input');
     if ('placeholder' in test) jQuery.support.placeholder = true;
 });
 // This adds placeholder support to browsers that wouldn't otherwise support it.
 $(function () {

     if (!$.support.placeholder) {
         var active = document.activeElement;
         $(':text').focus(function () {
             if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
                 $(this).val('').removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
             }
         }).blur(function () {
             if ($(this).attr('placeholder') != '' && ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder'))) {
                 $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
             }
         });
         $(':text').blur();
         $(active).focus();
         $('form:eq(0)').submit(function () {
             $(':text.hasPlaceholder').val('');
         });
     }
 });
```

When I am taking the value of **test**,it shows null.How can I get the details of all input tag?

Comment: place holder attribute will not support on less than IE 10

Comment: @Deepu Looks like OP knows that, and is trying to implement a workaround...

Comment: @Deepu OP's code is a shim for `placeholder` support...

Comment: That's the whole point of the code - patching alternative support into IE9 and older for the missing attribute.

Comment: Instead of using value better is to use text file (like label) that have css that will position it on top of the input box, and code will show/hide on focus/blur, because someone may put exact text as placeholder and it will not work.

Comment: There already is a plugin for this http://plugins.jquery.com/placeholder/

Comment: there are a whole *stack* of polyfill scripts for this... see https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder

Comment: People and their jquery plugins. Talk about let everyone else do the work

Comment: @Pinocchio why re-invent the wheel ?

Comment: Because that's how you learn if you're a "jquery developer" that just plants a load of plugins in your page and hope they work you're probaby going to get a lot of problems that you don't know how to fix. And its also fun to write your own stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
                    $("input").each(function () {
                        if (IsNull($(this).val()) && $(this).attr("placeholder") != "") {
                            $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder")).addClass('hasPlaceHolder');
                            $(this).keypress(function () {
                                if ($(this).hasClass('hasPlaceHolder')) $(this).val("").removeClass('hasPlaceHolder');
                            });
                            $(this).blur(function () {
                                if ($(this).val() == "") $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder")).addClass('hasPlaceHolder');
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my mobile so this is hard but really you need to do

```
JQuery.support.placeholder = typeof 'placeholder' in test !== 'undefined'
```

Because null means there isn't any placeholder value, but there is placeholder support

From what I understand you're saying that the placeholder in test is returning null

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you don't write this yourself and go for an off-the-shelf solution. There's more complexity here that you'd probably want to tackle yourself if all you want is provide support for older browsers.

For example, here's the shim I'm using (and that is recommended on http://html5please.com): https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js

Go ahead and read the code. These are some issues you need to have in mind when writing such shim:

- detect the browser support,
- keep track when the box contains the real input or not;
- add a class to allow different text colour for the placeholder,
- clear the placeholders before submitting the form,
- clear the placeholders when reloading the page,
- handle `textarea`,
- handle `input[type=password]`

And that's probably not even all. (The library I've linked also hooks into jQuery in order to make `.val()` return `''` when there's no real input in the box.

---

There's also another shim that uses a totally different approach: https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim/blob/master/jquery.html5-placeholder-shim.js

This library doesn't touch the actual value of the input, but instead displays an element directly over it.

Answer (score -3):

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='your_field' value='Enter value'/>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#your_field").on('focusout',function(){
        if($("#your_field").val() == ''){
            $("#your_field").val('Enter value');
        }
    });
    $("#your_field").on('focus',function(){
        if($("#your_field").val() == 'Enter value'){
            $("#your_field").val('');
        }
    });
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/INIDebI/1/edit)

Also check when the form is posted because if the user submits the form without entering the field then `Enter value` will be posted as the value of the field.So do either validations in client side or check in the server side when submitting the form.

Comment: Can the downvotters check the demo.?

Comment: I typed "Enter value" and clicked the text box, and my text disappeared.

Comment: What's terrible about this approach is, If the user submit the form without modifying the fake-placeholder-values it will submit it with the default data unlike placeholder that will submit empty values. You should point out that because newbies might use your 100% perfectly valid code, still the can't figure out why the placeholder text is sometimes posted on their forms!

Comment: Thats a good one @AhmadAlfy.Thank you for pointing this out.I have mentioned it in my answer.